# Enhancing $U(1)$ gauge symmetry of QED

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, charge, group-theory

QED is a gauge theory based on $U(1)$ gauge symmetry, which gives rise to the photon-the gauge boson mediating the interaction. Mathematically, I think it is perfectly allowed to implement a $U(1)\times U(1)$ gauge symmetry coupled to fermions. Physically, this is true only if the fermions are assumed to carry, in addition to electric charge, some other hidden/proposed $U(1)$ charge. *Is my line of thought correct?*

1. *If yes, we will have two gauge bosons. But I was wondering what distinguishes between these two gauge groups. Is it only the different $U(1)$ charge assignments that distinguish the groups?*
2. *Isn't the direct product of two $U(1)$ gauge transformation is always combined into a single $U(1)$ transformation?*
3. *And if that is true, what is the guarantee that there will be two distinct gauge bosons, and not one?*

Comment: QED is the most successful theory in physics in terms of its ability to describe experimental results. Why would you believe it needs "enhancement" by adding another gauge boson?

Comment: I'm not trying to modify QED but thinking about some particle physics model. QED is just an example.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct, postulating a $U(1)\times U(1)$ local symmetry would (almost by definition) give rise to two massless (vector) bosons, instead of one. The group $U(1)\times U(1)$ (due to its topological equivalence with the torus) must be abelian, in the sense that it doesn't matter the order in which you perform the gauge transformations, the result must be the same. The most important consequence of this fact is that the gauge fields always transform independently of one another; thus,for example, we can have two different values for the charges (this is not obvious for general product groups, as you could define a non-commutative group operation). The product of the two $U(1)$'s, then, not only does not combine into one single $U(1)$ (there is no reason that it would be so, and in fact never happens when you take the product of two groups), but gives rise to completely independent gauge fields, with non-coupled equation of motion (in the interaction-free case), thus independent quantized solutions, thus different gauge bosons. The difference between the two doesn't lie in the fact that you can have different charges (this, in fact, would depend on the interactions that you introduce in the theory), it lies in the fact that you have two separate gauge fields. Even in non-abelian gauge theories, where the interaction-free Lagrangian leads to coupled equations for the gauge fields, there are still $\dim\ G$ ($G$ gauge group) gauge fields, thus $\dim\ G$ different gauge bosons.

$$
$$

Consider the Lagrangian

$$
\mathcal{L}=i\bar{\psi}\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\psi-m\,\bar{\psi}\psi
$$

where

$$
\bar{\psi}=(\bar{\psi}_{1},\bar{\psi}_{2})\,,\qquad \psi=\begin{pmatrix}\psi_{1}\\\psi_{2}\end{pmatrix},\qquad\gamma^{\mu}=\begin{pmatrix}\gamma^{\mu}&0\\0&\gamma^{\mu}\end{pmatrix}
$$
and $\psi_{1}$ and $\psi_{2}$ are Dirac fields. $\mathcal{L}$ is invariant under the following *global* $U(1)\times U(1)$ transformation:

$$
\psi\to\begin{pmatrix}e^{i\phi_{1}}&0\\0&e^{i\phi_{2}}\end{pmatrix}\psi
$$
where $\phi_{1}$ and $\phi_{2}$ are independent real numbers. One can then localize the symmetry by defining a covariant derivative $D_{\mu}$ as

$$
D_{\mu}=\partial_{\mu}+ie\,f_{i}\,A_{\mu}^{i}
$$
where $i=1,2$ and

$$
f_{1}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\,,\qquad f_{2}=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}
$$
As you can see, $[f_{1},f_{2}]=0$. Taking into account the usual cinetic term for the gauge field, we have the total Lagrangian
$$
\mathcal{L}=i\bar{\psi}\gamma^{\mu}D_{\mu}\psi-m\,\bar{\psi}\psi+\sum_{i=1}^{2}\frac{1}{4}\,F_{\mu\nu\,i}F^{\mu\nu\,i}
$$
Now, in the case of a general gauge group, the *curvature* form $F$ is defined geometrically by

$$
F_{\mu\nu}^{i}=(dA^{i})_{\mu\nu}+[A,A]^{i}
$$
Where $dA$ is the exterior derivative of $A$ and $[A,A]$ is the commutator between the elements of the algebra. In this case the group is abelian, so

$$
F_{\mu\nu}^{i}=\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}^{i}-\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}^{i}
$$
Explicitly, the Lagrangian reads:

$$
\mathcal{L}=\sum_{i=1}^{2}\left\{i\bar{\psi_{i}}\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\psi_{i}-m\,\bar{\psi_{i}}\psi_{i}+\frac{1}{4}\,F_{\mu\nu\,i}F^{\mu\nu\,i}-e\,\bar{\psi}_{i}\gamma^{\mu}\psi_{i}A_{\mu}^{i}\right\}
$$
so it splits into two formally identical Lagrangians, each one containing only *one* potential $A_{\mu}^{i}$. Now, as they are identical, their quantization brings to formally identical results, and it is equivalent to two copies of standard spinor electrodynamics. The degrees of freedom, though formally identical, are separate, in the sense that $\psi_{1}\neq\psi_{2}$ and $A_{\mu}^{1}\neq A_{\mu}^{2}$: they appear as different in the Lagrangian, they have their own equations of motion, and thus must correspond to different fields. Moreover, there exists no interaction between the $i=1$ fields of the Lagrangian and the $i=2$ fields. This means that, as you human being are made of the, say, $i=1$ fields, you will never be able to even know of the existence of the $i=2$ fields: no experiment can be performed to prove that they exist. In order to implement the $U(1\times U(1)$ symmetry in a physically significant way, you should embed the group $U(1)\times U(1)$ in a larger group, in a way that allows the $i=1$ and $i=2$ fields to interact.

$$
$$
Some asides on the previous discussion. First of all, in defining the matrices $f_{i}$, you could multiply each of them by a different number, and you would not spoil the symmetry. It is true that different representations must have charges that are integer multiples of a fundamental one, but here we are talking about how to represent two different portions of the same group. Second of all, you could think that the symmetry can be realized through only one Dirac field, with covariant derivative

$$
D_{\mu}=\partial_{\mu}+ie\,A_{\mu}^{1}+ie'\,A_{\mu}^{2}
$$
But the gauge transformation that corresponds to this derivative is of the form
$$
\psi\to\exp{i(e\,\chi_{1}+e'\,\chi_{2})}\,\psi
$$
and this is *not* an element of $U(1)\times U(1)$: it is still an element of $U(1)$. In fact we have only one exponential, and one exponential can't realize the two-dimensional topolgy of $U(1)\times U(1)$. On the other hand, a Lagrangian with the above covariant derivative is perfectly well-defined, and still gives rise to two different vector bosons. It just won't be a $U(1)\times U(1)$ gauge-invariant Lagrangian. Finally, the representations of $U(1)\times U(1)$ are classified by two integer numbers $(n,m)$ which express the charges of the objects of the representation. Thus, the physics predicted by using any one representation of $U(1)\times U(1)$ is equivalent to the one in the above example, up to the value of the charges.

Comment: Why do you say that there are two gauge bosons? Is it because that the direct product of two U(1) symmetries must act on two independent vector spaces? Since in this case, both the vector spaces will have the same dimensionality, I'm having tough time to visualize what would those vector spaces be or be spanned by? Can you clarify it with an example?

Comment: The rigorous standard argument goes as follows. A gauge group is usually defined as a Lie group acting on some vector bundle over Minkowski spacetime. To be able to define it in a geometrically rigorous way, one must postulate the existence of a gauge potential, i.e. a 1-form taking values in the Lie algebra of the gauge group. The Lie algebra of $U(1)\times U(1)$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{R}^{2}$, so one must require the existence of two different covector fields taking values in $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: As for the objects on which the group acts, they must be fields with values in a vector space carrying a faithful representation of the group. The only irreducible faithful finite-dimensional representation of $U(1)\times U(1)$ is on $\Bbb{C}^{2}$, but in each complex component one could add extra structure as for example a bispinor structure, thus obtaining a theory of Dirac fields coupled to the gauge fields. The two fields, however, don't transform into each other under a gauge transformation. This is because the representation can be diagonalized: each U(1) acts on a different Dirac field

Comment: I'll add an actual Lagrangian to the answer after having dinner.

Comment: Done. Let me know.

Comment: Still I have a doubt. When you write $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$, do you mean two different Dirac fields, or the same field? Can I not apply $U(1)_a\times U(1)_b$ gauge invariance in a single Dirac field $\psi=\psi_a\otimes \psi_b$ characterized by two different U(1) charges $a$ and $b$? The point I wanted to convey is that, can I not have two different $U(1)$ charges for the same fermion, (say, electron)? One is the usual electric charge and the other is some “hidden U(1)” charge?

Comment: Moreover, for a U(1) theory, the term $F^{\mu\nu}$ is itself gauge invariant. Therefore, the Lagrangian can certainly contain a term like $\propto F^1_{\mu\nu}F^{2\mu\nu}$. Which in turn implies that there can certainly be a mixing between the two gauge bosons $A_\mu^1$ and $A_\mu^2$. However, it may be possible to go to a basis where there is no interaction between $A_\mu^1$ and $A_\mu^2$.

Comment: Yes, I meant two different Dirac fields. Be more specific about what you mean by $\psi_{a}\otimes \psi_{b}$, there is no such product defined between fields. You can indeed define, as I said at the end, two different "U(1) fields" acting on a single Dirac field, but that wouldn't be a $U(1)\times U(1)$ gauge-invariant theory at all. In fact, the topology of $U(1)\times U(1)$ is that of a torus $\Bbb{S}^{1}\times \Bbb{S}^{1}$, but in using the last covariant derivative I wrote, you wouldn't be implementing in the theory toroidal gauge transformations.

Comment: On the other hand, let's say you are ok with that. This means you won't be having a $U(1)\times U(1)$ symmetry in the strict sense, but you'd still have a well-defined Lagrangian. Then the two fields are coupled with one Dirac field. This means that they are indirectly (i.e. through the Dirac field) coupled to one another, so in principle you don't need the $F^{1}_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}_{2}$ term to couple them. But, as you said, this term is acceptable as it is gauge invariant with respect to each $U(1)$ transformation.

Comment: Anyways, you should be cautious when talking about gauge symmetry in the case that the derivative is of the form $D_{\mu}=\partial_{\mu}+ie_{1}\,A_{\mu}^{1}+ie_{2}\,A_{\mu}^{2}$. This is not a regular gauge-covariant derivative, in the sense that when you postulate a gauge symmetry, most certainly you don't get such a covariant derivative (the reason for this is in my first comment: there won't be linear combinations of the gauge fields, as you would get a "local" basis of the Lie algebra of the group instead). Thus your theory doesn't have the structure of a gauge theory.

Comment: For example, let's say you transform the single Dirac field as $\psi\to \exp(i\chi(x))\psi$. This is a $U(1)$ local transformation, but there is no way to decide which of the $A$'s should absorb the transformation. This implies that the gauge structure is ill-defined: your theory looks like a gauge theory, but it really is not. On the other hand it is a well-defined quantum theory; in particular, it would be consistent with the masslessness of the $A$ particles.

Comment: It all depends on what you specifically mean by a theory being gauge-invariant: you theory doesn't have a well defined gauge-structure, but in the end it accepts gauge-like transformations, which in turn means, for example, that the $A$ particles will indeed be massless. Uh, by the way. Your second charge wouldn't be hidden at all: it would have the very same status as the first one.